# my recursiveSort() method not working? (generics)

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, recursion

I'm supposed to create a method that takes an ArrayList of Bounded Generic type and sorts it based on the volumes of the objects using the following algorithm (I HAVE to follow it exactly). The bound should only allow any Shape object and subclasses:

```
if the list size is <= 1
   return the list
select a middle element from the list and remove it
create two lists leftList and rightList
for each element in the list
   if element is less than the middle element then add element to the rightList
   else add element to leftList
return the combination of recursiveSort(leftList), middle element, and recursiveSort(rightList)
```

My Shape class is simply just an interface with a getVolume() method where my other classes (Spheres, Ellipsoid, etc.) override this method

And here is my recursive code (in another class that does other methods such as find min and max):

```
public class ShapeUtilities {
public static <T extends Shape> Collection<? extends T> recursiveSort(ArrayList<T> list) {

    if (list.size() <= 1) {
        return list;
    }
    int middleIndex = list.size() / 2;
    T middleElement = list.get(middleIndex);
    list.remove(middleIndex);
    ArrayList<T> leftList = new ArrayList<T>();
    ArrayList<T> rightList = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T item : list) {
        if (item.getVolume() < middleIndex) {
            rightList.add(item);
        } else {
            leftList.add(item);
        }
    }       

    ArrayList<? extends Shape> combination = new ArrayList<T>();
combination.addAll(recursiveSort(leftList));
    combination.add(middleElement);
    combination.addAll(recursiveSort(rightList));
    return combination;
```

How can I return the "combination of recursiveSort(leftList), middle element, and recursiveSort(rightList)"? It's not adding into the ArrayList I created and simply just returns the middle element instead of all three.

Comment: (this is a quick sort)

Comment: (you missed `recursiveSort` call on your `rightList`)

Comment: `list.get(i).getVolume() < middleIndex` is wrong. you want to `list.get(i).getVolume() < middleElement.getVolume()`

Comment: Can you post a [(short) complete program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see the results for yourself, and to eliminate the chance that the problem is in code you didn't post?

Comment: `list.size() - 1` skims the last element of the list. If `getVolume()` is globally more than the size of the list, due to the faulty test, every thing goes to leftlist, which is called recursively until only one element remains.

Comment: why don't you use a fast enumeration for looping on the `list` ?

Comment: In case you didn't quite get @njzk2's first comment, the algorithm you have here is essentially the well-known [quick-sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) (albeit a little different from the standard implementation).

Comment: It looks like you fixed the code in your question (based on the answers) (at least to some extent), which has now invalidated most of the answers. It would be more in line with [so] guidelines to leave your question with the unworking code, and post the working solution as an **answer** instead (that is, if you want to do more than simply accepting the answer that helped you the most).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining my various comments:

The first issue is

```
list.size() - 1
```

This will remove one element at each recursion

Then

```
list.get(i).getVolume() < middleIndex
```

Should be

```
list.get(i).getVolume() < middleElement.getVolume()
```

You are comparing a volume with an index. If the volume is a value that is generally greater than the size of the list, all items go to `leftList`

Finally

```
combination.addAll(rightList);
```

Does not sort the `rightList`.

The reason why you receive very few items in the end is because the skimming in the loop fills `leftList` with all but one element, minus the middle element.

In the end you only receive the middle elements.

Last note, there is no reason in your code for using the old `for` loop. You can use the fast enumeration notation:

```
for (T item: list) {
    if (item.getVolume() < middleItem.getVolume()) {
        leftList.add(item);
    } else {
        rightList.add(item);
    }
}
```

This ensures enumeration over the complete list, without ambiguity of indices or risk of errors such as looping until `list.size() - 1`

Comment: Thank you so much! I have made the fixes (and added my extra classes for the person who wanted to see a short complete program). But I still get the error that I can't add the the new sort list to another ArrayList and return it.

Comment: I don't understand your comment `I can't add the the new sort list to another ArrayList`. What is happening when you run the code? when you debug it? What error do you have?

Comment: Actually, nevermind I looked over it again (made a few corrections) and it seems to print out the Objects in the correct order. Thank you so much for the help!! : )

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
```

There should not be a `-1` here.  You're skipping your last element.

```
combination.addAll(rightList);
```

You are never sorting `rightList`, you're just simply taking it as is.

Comment: Although this still doesn't explain why it "just returns the middle element instead of all three" (which admittedly doesn't seem to make much sense, hence I asked for a complete program in a comment).

Comment: @Dukeling Right, the only way it seems this code should return a single element is if the initial list only had 2 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and I guess your test would need to be:

```
    if (list.get(i).getVolume() < middleElement.getVolume()) {
```